# Retrieving ArcGIS Collector points when service definition was deleted?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-collector, delete, service-definition

I made a service to collect data points in the field, but then right before leaving updated the fields and deleted the old service, and published my new service. I assumed the Collector for ArcGIS app would automatically update. I am now stuck with data that belongs to a service definition that no longer exists.

Is there any way that I can upload these points without the original service definition they came from?

Comment: You wont be able to overwrite the service if the SD file has been removed. I am not sure if you are asking about sync'ing your data from Collector b/c you killed the service. If you want to sync it with another service you will have to do that using the Runtime GDB to FDBG tool and bring over your edits to the other layer.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my first foray into using collector and ArcGIS online, and so a lot of this is new to me. What is the Runtime GDB to FDGB tool? Is this done with python?

Comment: Its a tool in ArcMap. http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012460